# _remap ignoring IS_AJAX call?

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, post, controller, remap

This issue is very likely codeigniter specific.

I have a controller called redirect.php that redirects from and to views. This controller for the most part has one public `_remap` function that does all the redirecting with a case statement. Everything has been working great until I sent a `$.POST` from a view back to the controller. I want it to hit the _remap and look for the fact that the request is coming from AJAX then do it’s case.

I have a `IS_AJAX` constant I’m checking against.

```
define('IS_AJAX', isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest');
```

but whenever I hit the page it’s always remapping to the default and sending my request to that page where it’s basically returning me that pages data back when I’m echoing and alerting the data to and fro.

Any insights?

for reference,

redirect.php (there is more code to define variables and 2 more cases but it's not hitting those, it's hitting 'index' / default)

```
 public function _remap($method)
        {   

    switch ($method) {
        case $method == 'index':
        $this->load->view('main');
            break;
        case $method == 'IS_AJAX':
        var_dump($_POST);
            break;
        default:
        $this->load->view('main');
            }
        }
```

tweetview.php (view loaded by redirect controller in another case within redirect.php, json_tweets send is a JSON variable)

//jquery

```
$.post("http://localhost/2fb/index.php/redirect", {'json_tweets': json_tweets},
   function(data) {
     alert(data);
   });
```

Comment: need to see more of what's going on, please post your controller and the javascript you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
case $method == 'IS_AJAX':
```

Your `$method` is not `IS_AJAX` with this url:

```
http://localhost/2fb/index.php/redirect
```

This would bring you to the `redirect` controller without a method (will default to "index"). You literally would need:

```
http://localhost/2fb/index.php/redirect/IS_AJAX
```

...to step into that `case`. You seem to be confusing your *constant* `IS_AJAX` with the method requested, which you seem to be using correctly when checking for `index` (although this is the same as the `default` case, so it's redundant).

`$method`, or whatever you name the first parameter in `_remap()`, will always be the routed controller function that is called.

**EDIT**: I failed to mention this earlier, but the switch block evaluates the expression you pass to it, so there is no need to do the comparison manually. Example:

```
switch ($method) {
    // case $method === 'index':
    case 'index':
        $this->load->view('main');
    break;
}
```

Comment: oh wow, your right of course. That's what i get for coding at 2am on a controller I haven't looked at in days. :) I'm going to have to rethink this strategy.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing all this you can rely on `$this->input->is_ajax_request()` from http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html. If you are not interested in loading a library, here is somewhat similar code I have in production for last two years at least.

```
$ajax = ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']==='XMLHttpRequest')? true : false;
```

Look at the string, its  `XMLHttpRequest` and the jQuery is the frontend JS toolkit

Just to add more, I usually have one entry point for Ajax calls, so obviously I have one controller for ajax and route all my calls through it. Why would I do that? Simple reason, I make sure all my forms submit to a simple non ajax form handler at server if JS is turned off. If JS is on, jQuery/prototype/YUI takes control and sends data to my ajax controller. The end handler which actually does all the validation/verification/db interaction is common code.

Comment: Looks like he's already doing that with a constant, which is also what I do.

Comment: Well yes, my intention is to point him to CI function/method that takes care of doing what I, you and he is doing.

Comment: interesting, I didn't know about that library function. I have no problem using libraries and since I'm already loading input, I'll definitely check it out.

Comment: The Input class is always loaded, you don't have to load it manually.

Comment: @egfx, I noticed it not more than 15 days ago and I have been using CI for last 2 years and 7 months :(

Comment: lol, me too. And I thought I was good at reading the CI docs especially on libraries i'm loading. I swear it's the first time I saw this myself.

Answer (score 0):

try this ,

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "your function url goes here",
        data: data,
        success: function(html){
              window.location = 'redirect url goes here';
        }
   });
```

Comment: yep, I see based on my confusion over the issue why this answer makes some sense. Have added validation to use another separate ajax controller that @kumar suggested so that's the direction I'll actually go with.